# How to find the 32-bit of a number

Tags: javascript, 32-bit, bitwise-and

Can I ask how to find the 32-bit version of a number as I want to work around with numbers with the bitwise AND operator in JavaScript. It stated that the numbers perform bitwise operations in 32bit version.

Second question is it in JavaScript bitwise AND operator(&), the operation of numbers perform in 32-bit version, right? Then at the end does it convert it back to 64-bit version?

Comment: Mozilla's MDN has [some information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Answer (score 5):

According to [the ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), the return values from bitwise operations must be 32-bit integers. A relevant quote:

> The production `A : A @ B`, where `@` is
>   one of the bitwise operators in the
>   productions above, is evaluated as 
>   follows:
>
> 1. Let `lref` be the result of evaluating `A`.
> 2. Let `lval` be `GetValue(lref)`.
> 3. Let `rref` be the result of evaluating `B`.
> 4. Let `rval` be `GetValue(rref)`.
> 5. Let `lnum` be `ToInt32(lval)`.
> 6. Let `rnum` be `ToInt32(rval)`.
> 7. Return the result of applying the bitwise operator `@` to `lnum` and `rnum`.
>
> **The result is a signed 32 bit integer.**

Therefore to convert any number to a 32-bit integer, you can just perform a binary operation that would have no effect. For example, here I convert a float to an integer using a no-op binary or (`| 0`):

```
var x = 1.2, y = 1
x = x | 0
alert(x == y) # prints "true"
```